# What do "underfull" warnings mean?

Tags: warnings

What does this warning message mean?

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 49--50

This is my code, I can't see what happens, it is a simple itemize. As you see, there is an admiration symbol, I don't know what is going on.

[image]

I have also this warning, another admiration symbol:

Underfull \hbox (badness 6893) in paragraph at lines 77--78

[image]

I am working in article as class document. That is just text, no reference mode.

Comment: These are *warnings*, not *errors*.

Comment: Thank you very much! your tag help me solve my problem! Kind  regards.

Comment: @Werner thanks for your answer. Your tag help me to understand what was      happening. Thank you very much. Kind regards.